# Play! Framework 2.X, form handling

Tags: forms, object, playframework

I am new to using Play! Framework 2.X and have a simple question. 
How can i send to my method Job.create(filledJob) a fully set Job object? Meaning that Company object including in Job object is filled too.

I have the following:

```
public class Job {  
    public String title;
    public Company company;
 }

public class Company {
     public String name;
     public String email;   
}
```

I have a form in my template, containing a Job information section and a Company section

```
@(jobForm: Form[Job], companyForm: Form[Company])
@form(routes.Application.newJob()) {      
    @inputText(jobForm("title"))             
    @inputText(companyForm("name"))                       
    <input type="submit" value="Create">     
}
```

My controller(Application.java) looks like that:

```
  public class Application extends Controller {

    static Form<Job> jobForm = form(Job.class); 
    static Form<Company> companyForm = form(Company.class);

    public static Result index() {
       return ok(
         views.html.index.render(jobForm, companyForm)
      );
    }

    public static Result newJob() {
       Form<Job> filledForm = jobForm.bindFromRequest();
       Job.create(filledForm.get());
       return redirect(routes.Application.index()); 
    }
}
```

Ideally, i would like to send to my method Job.create(job), with job with all the fields set (string job title as well as Company object). It must be a numpty question, i appologize for that. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: how about jobForm.fill(job) ?

Comment: I am not sure where you are heading to. I only need a Job object set from the form that i can send to my method Job.create

Comment: Ah, sorry, read the question a little too fast and misunderstood.

Comment: are you going to create and save Job AND Company objects in one form ? or rather Company exists and you only want to relate it to new Job?

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, however the company does not exists yet and is part of the Job object. I was thinking of doing something like that but it does not seem to be like a good practice :    Job job = form(Job.class).bindFromRequest().get();
   job.company.name = form().bindFromRequest().get("name");

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `@inputText(companyForm("name"))` if you want bind the form directly into object, but instead you can use a `select` form helper for selecting the company, check ie. [`computer-database`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/samples/java/computer-database/app/views/createForm.scala.html) sample it's quite similar case...

On the other hand if you have a lot of companies and don't want to create huge `select` consider another scenario: just instead route like `/job/new` use `/company/:companyId/add-job` in other words just you'll send a form and bind it from request + additionaly will get Company by id in route param and will add to object, pseudo code:

```
public static Result addJobToCompany(Integer companyId){

    Job job = form(Job.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    job.company = Company.find.byId(companyId);
    job.save();

    return redirect(routes.Application.jobDetails(job.id));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i am replying to my own question as i must not have explained my question clearly.
To make it simple : I needed to set the Company object from a form. Find below my solution
Hope it will help you.

```
public class Job {  
    public String title;
    @Valid
    public Company company;
}

public class Company {
     public String name;
     public String email;   
}

@(jobForm: Form[Job], companyForm: Form[Company])
  @form(routes.Application.newJob()) {      
  @inputText(jobForm("title"))             
  @inputText(jobForm("company.name"))                       
 <input type="submit" value="Create">     
}
```